# Comparing three integer values

Tags: java, javascript

Is something like this ever possible?

```
if(a == b == c)
```

or is

```
if((a== b) && (b == c))
```

is the only way?

or what is the coolest way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In some languages you *can* use that shorthand. For example in Python `a == b == c` is roughly equivalent to the expression `a == b and b == c`, except that b is only evaluated once.

However in Java and Javascript you *can't* use the short version - you have to write it as in the second example. The first example would be approximately equivalent to the following:

```
boolean temp = (a == b);
if (temp == c) {
    // ...
}
```

This is not what you want. In Java `a == b == c` won't even compile unless `c` is a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

In java - we don't have the == shortcut operator. so we end up doing individual equalities.

But If you think you will need functionality a lot with **varying** number of arguments, I would consider implementing a function like this. The following is the sample code without handling exceptional conditions.

```
 public static boolean areTheyEqual(int... a) {
        int VALUE = a[0];   
        for(int i: a) {
            if(i!= VALUE)
                return false;
        }       
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, your safest bet is `a === b && b === c`. I always avoid using `==` in favor of `===` for my own sanity. [Here's a more detailed explanation.](http://www.2ality.com/2011/06/javascript-equality.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Scala you can use tuples for this:

`(a, b) == (c, c)`

This will check `a == c` and `b == c`, i.e same as `a == b == c`

Answer (score -2):

To get the max value out of three numbers, one line method:

**int max = (a > b && a > c) ? a : ((b > a && b > c) ? b : c);**